# Excluding a commit from a PR that is already in a PR

Tags: git, github

I have an open PR with a commit I did

I made another commit and want to create another PR with just these changes.. however the previous commit is in there.

I realize branches would resolve this, yet, here we are. Do I just need to wait for the PR to be merged?

Comment: Why not just revert it?

Comment: What is the point of keeping in a private branch a revision you actually don't want in history? Just get the history fixed, no need to revert. #imho

Answer (score 1):

> *I have an open PR with a commit I did*

At that point your repository looked something like this.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C [pr1]
```

Commit B is where `master` is at. And you have a branch called `pr1` with a commit C on it.

> *I made another commit and want to create another PR with just these changes.. however the previous commit is in there.*

What probably happened is you branched from `pr1` rather than `master` resulting in this.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C [pr1]
       \
        D [pr2]
```

When you make a PR for `pr2` by default the base branch is `master` so it shows `C` and `D` in the PR.

---

If the work in ***`D` does not depend on `C`*** what you want is for `pr2` and commit `D` to be branched from `master`.

```
      D [pr2]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      C [pr1]
```

You can fix this by rebasing `pr2` onto `master`.

```
git rebase --onto master pr1 pr2
```

That says to replay the commits starting at (but not including) `pr1` to (and including) `pr2` onto `master`. Then you can push `pr2` and create an independent PR.

---

If the work in ***`D` does depend on `C`*** then it's best to leave `pr2` on top of `pr1`. Create a PR for `pr2` with the base being `pr1` instead of `master`. Once `pr1` is reviewed and accepted, then `pr2` can be reviewed and accepted.

Be sure to make a note in the PR description that `pr2` is stacked on top of `pr1` so the reviewer doesn't miss it. "This depends on #123" where #123 is the ID of `pr1`'s PR.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new branch from whatever point you want to start and cherry-pick the other branch. That will apply the changes involved on the last revision of the other branch and no other changes (assuming it's the last revision from that branch).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this, is by using [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

If you run `git log --oneline` on your branch, you should see something that looks like this:

---

```
ccccccc (HEAD -> your-branch-name) Your (good) commit you want to keep
bbbbbbb bbbbbbb Your (bad) commit you want to remove from history
aaaaaaa (master) Commit from you or someone else
```

---

[image: current]

You say you want to remove `bbbbbbb` replacing it with `ccccccc`.

Because `ccccccc` contains changes since `bbbbbbb`, removing it would cause lots of conflicts, as you'd have to merge `ccccccc` into `aaaaaaa`.

The `git` way to do it, is to [*squash*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_squashing) `ccccccc` into `bbbbbbb`, creating a new commit `ddddddd`. And for that, you'd do the following steps:

**1**. Run `git rebase -i aaaaaaa` to open the interactive rebase, starting from the commit immediatelly before the one you want to remove

This will open your configured text editor with something that looks like this:

---

```
pick bbbbbbb Your (bad) commit you want to remove from history
pick ccccccc Your (good) commit you want to keep

# Rebase aaaaaaa..f5a9551 onto aaaaaaa (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
#   However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
#   
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

---

The list shows what the interactive rebase will do:
From `aaaaaaa`, pick `bbbbbbb`, then pick `ccccccc`

**2**. As I said above, you want to [*squash*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_squashing) `ccccccc` into `bbbbbbb`, so replace the word `pick` before `ccccccc` by `squash`:

---

```
pick bbbbbbb Your (bad) commit you want to remove from history
squash ccccccc Your (good) commit you want to keep
```

---

**3**. Save the file, and close the text editor.

**4**. Another text editor will open, to ask you to specify the message of the new commit being created, with the combination of `ccccccc` and `bbbbbbb` - which I'm calling `ddddddd` for the sake of this example:

---

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

Your (bad) commit you want to remove from history

# This is the commit message #2:

Your (good) commit you want to keep
```

---

Here you probably want to delete everything except the last line, which has the message of your latest commit, but feel free to customize the message however you like.

**5**. Save the file, and close the text editor.

The rebase is done, and your history should look like this:

---

```
ddddddd (HEAD -> your-branch-name) Your (good) commit you want to keep
aaaaaaa (master) Commit from you or someone else
```

---

[image: before pushing]

**6**. Now, all you have to do is to send to push the branch back to your `origin` (e.g. GitHub/BitBucket/GitLab), etc. in order to update your pull-request.

For that, you'll have to do a **`push --force`**, so that your remote branch is replaced by this new one.

---

```
git push origin your-branch-name --force
```

---

[image: final result]

Of course, you always have the option of closing the previous pull-request and opening a new one instead (with a different branch name).